# How can I learn from a failed review audit, I can't see the post I was supposed to delete?

Tags: support, review-audits, deleted-answers

I was reviewing in the "low quality posts" queue and I [failed a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4963890).    I got a message saying that the post contained "nothing of value" and that I should have recommended deletion.

My recollection of the post in question was nothing of the sort.  From what I remember the post that I was reviewing had -4 votes, started with a crass remark to the effect of "lol you said git", but otherwise contained a real answer that was horribly formatted.  The entire answer was formatted as code, and extended well off the screen to the right with scroll bars.

I clicked "edit" so that I could fix up the formatting and immediately failed the review.  Now I can't even see the post, presumably because it is deleted content.  Maybe if I could see it I could see why the system thinks it has no value whatsoever.   As it stands, I don't see how I could be expected to learn from this experience.

Comment: Did you honestly think that post was salvageable by editing it?  I mean, it starts out with `lol u sed git`, and just goes downhill from there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Some people like to make jokes even while being helpful.  I hadn't noticed that the "answer" was a copy and paste of the question.  When I clicked "edit", I had seen that the grammar and spelling seemed to be OK and it actually contained some code.  It was hard to assess more because the formatting was so bad.  Presumably, I would have realized while editing it that the was asking a question (actually the same question) rather than answering.

Comment: Boy, it [sure would be nice if reviewers could see deleted posts they reviewed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed) Just sayin'.

Answer (score 8):

That was not an answer. It was just a copy and paste of the question (other than the "lol ..." line).

Comment: Thank you.  That explains a lot.  I hadn't noticed that.  Shouldn't I be able to see it after I failed though?

Comment: It does seem like it would be helpful for <10K users to be able to see deleted content in the case of an audit failure (to help see exactly why), but I don't know the official policy/thinking.

Comment: This leaves unaddressed the problem that the user clicked "edit" in order to improve the post - if that can lead to an **automated** review failure, it's a serious site bug.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  It said it had "no redeeming value" and editing wouldn't have fixed it.   If it is juvenile humor, followed by a copy of the question, I'd agree with that.  Nothing to do but delete it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - that something has "no redeeming value" and "editing wouldn't have fixed it" is precisely the sort of claim which **should never be made by an automated system** - even the live humans here have a pretty poor track record with such claims.  Editing is far too open-ended a possibility to ever result in a audit failure *before* the results of the edit are seen by humans.

Comment: Faced in real life with badly formatted text and/or code, my immediate reaction is to edit the formatting. I do that before even trying to evaluate the content. The point of good formatting is that it makes reading **much** faster and easier. It seems to me that the audit system jumps the gun in some situations. It should wait until the reviewer makes a definite decision, not react to attempted investigation.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Couldn't agree more.